# How to get single predictions for a linear model in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I'm trying to make my results more intuitive, and so I want to compare the predicted values at the interquartile range. I'm trying to figure out how to get the predicted value for a given variable, keeping everything else at the median.

I've tried something like this:

```
x_1 <- rnorm(20)
x_2 <- rnorm(20)
y <- x_1 + x_2 + rnorm(20)
z <- data.frame(y,x_1,x_2)
fit <- lm(y~x_1 + x_2,data = z)
predict(fit,newdata = data.frame(x_1=c(quantile(x_1)[2],quantile(x_1)[4]), x_2=median(x_2)))
```

which works, but my actual model has 10+ variables, and this starts to get ugly really quickly, so I figure there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the apply() function is what you need here.

Try

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(20*10), ncol = 10, nrow = 20)
y <- apply(data, 1, sum) + rnorm(20)
z <- data.frame(y,data)
fit <- lm(y~ . ,data = z)

i <- 1  ### Predictions for variable i
meds  <- apply(data[,-i], 2, median)
new <- cbind(c(quantile(data[,i])[2],quantile(data[,i])[4]), matrix(meds, nrow = 2, ncol = length(meds), byrow = T))
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(new))
```